# Android launch various activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

first sorry for my english i speak spanish and my english is very bad.

i have a simple android application, this one:

MainActivity with one button to finish:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

And I have a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}}
```

When android start launch the application perfectly, but if i press the home button and then start the application, open a new activity, if i prees button of my app to close the activity it close but appears the old activity (MainActivity). What is the problem??

Thanks!!

Comment: the finish method finishes the current activity and open the last activity was opened before the current one , so this behaviour is normal , could you please tell me what your are trying to do ?

Comment: im working in an application than work in background, and you have to minimize the activity, and the activity show information, but if you are pressing open and home button all the time when you close application appears all the activities

Comment: i really cant understand what you are trying to say . 
the button that calls the finish method , what it should do ?

Comment: just that, close the activity. And it should show last activty, but if i press button appears again the activity.

Comment: what you want to do when you press the home button ?

Comment: i want to minimize the app

Comment: ok then what ? when you click on the application icon what you want to do ?

Comment: open the MainActivity, (but it open new activity), and if i finish with the button appear again a MainActivity

Comment: ok in the activity that you dont want to appear again , go to its declaration in the manifest and add this : android:noHistory="true"

Comment: thank it work but not the way i wanted, because my app is bigger and that doestn work for me because from mainctivity i launch another activity (Main activity is a login), when i go to second activity this connect with a server, and this is the activity i want to minimize, if i finish this second activity dont appears again the same(thak to you and nohistory:true), but if i launch again the application the second activity connect again with the server it should be connected before. sorry this is very complicated to explain

Comment: its strange because if i force stop app and launcha again works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to use a service to run your activity in the background so whenever you minimize your activity by pressing home button for example then restore it the activity doesn't restart.

so just google for an android service tutorial, it's very simple to implement.

Comment: im doing that, mi app works fine when i started it from normal way, launching from icon, but fail when i started from broadcastreceiver

Comment: i'm not sure you got me right and i'm not sure i got you, service is a superclass just like activity but it enables your application to work in the background.
you create a class that extends service then write some code inside , then in your activity you start the service class you have implemented.